# Algorithm to find minimum number of days to color boxes by one or more robots

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have `n` boxes which should be colored. Each day robot can color one box or generate another robot, who works exactly as his parent starting next day.

i.e., if on Sunday I have one robot and 10 balls, on Monday:

1. There is one robot, 1 colored boxes and 9 uncolored boxes, *or*
2. There are 2 robots and 10 uncolored boxes.

I need to find the minimum number of days to color all boxes.

I thought to solve that using dynamic programming:

```
T(n,1) = min(T(n-1,1) + 1, T(n,2))
```

But I am not sure how to create a DP matrix and if DP is correct approach at all.

Comment: Do you need to find the *number of ways* to color all boxes or the *minimum number of days* needed to color all boxes?

Comment: In order to create the matrix, don't you have to calculate T(x, y) for all possible values of x and y?

Comment: Dynamic programming is *one of several possible* approaches, so as such it is "correct".

Comment: Are we always starting with 1 bot?

Comment: Probably best to simply build more robots until you have enough to color all boxes in a single day, so answer will be 1 + ceil log2 of growth in number of robots required

Comment: @mkrieger1minimum number of days to color all boxes.

Comment: I also don't think you would need DP here. @PeterdeRivaz 's comment should be the correct solution

Comment: @vish4071 - yes

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz up until 1/2. Then you're better just colouring boxes, I think; the delay by 1 day causes you to lose a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Peter de Rivaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139393/peter-de-rivaz) notes, an optimal solution is to have all robots replicate until the job can be finished in one day, taking `1 + ceil(log_2(n))` days total.

You could write a dynamic programming solution, and it would work, but here you can show that this strategy is guaranteed to minimize the number of days.

Suppose that there is an optimal strategy where robot `r` paints a box on day `d`. Then, after day `d+2`, robot `r`'s output from the previous three days will be at most '3 boxes painted, 2 total robots (counting `r` itself)' or '1 box painted, 4 total robots.'

If instead the robot had replicated before painting, its output after day `d+2` from the previous three days would be '4 boxes painted, 4 total robots', which is strictly better than the alternatives and thus also optimal. So you can conclude that unless you will be done after day `d` or day `d+1`, it is always optimal to replicate on day `d`.

Now, what if you're done after day `d+1`? It's still optimal to replicate on day `d` rather than painting both days-- you get two boxes painted in two days either way, meaning that our strategy is at least as good as any other strategy.